# How to cache ADAL tokens between runs of a Python console application

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I am working on a project right now where the intent is to call a specific Microsoft Graph endpoint every minute from a python console app on a Raspberry Pi (if a certain value is returned, then kick off other Raspberry Pi processes). I was able to get the basics working based on the code available at this repo: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-console-app

However, since I want this to run every minute or so (and I was hoping to do so via crontab or something similar rather than a while loop in a constantly running script), the way the script is currently written, it requires a user to copy an authentication code into a web browser and confirm their account on every run, per the device code flow.  Ideally, I would like to do that browser-based authentication once, cache the token, and use that token as long as it is valid, or call refresh_token.

As I'm still fairly new to Python, I'm a little lost on how to persist tokens across runs. I am open to any recommendations.

Current auth code shown here:

```
import base64
import os
import urllib
import webbrowser
import json
from adal import AuthenticationContext
import pyperclip
import requests
import config

def api_endpoint(url):
    if urllib.parse.urlparse(url).scheme in ['http', 'https']:
        return url # url is already complete
    return urllib.parse.urljoin(f'{config.RESOURCE}/{config.API_VERSION}/',
                                url.lstrip('/'))

def device_flow_session(client_id, auto=False):
    ctx = AuthenticationContext(config.AUTHORITY_URL)
    device_code = ctx.acquire_user_code(config.RESOURCE,client_id)

    # display user instructions
    if auto:
        pyperclip.copy(device_code['user_code']) # copy user code to clipboard
        webbrowser.open(device_code['verification_url']) # open browser
        print(f'The code {device_code["user_code"]} has been copied to your clipboard, '
              f'and your web browser is opening {device_code["verification_url"]}. '
              'Paste the code to sign in.')
    else:
        print(device_code['message'])

    token_response = ctx.acquire_token_with_device_code(config.RESOURCE,
                                                        device_code,
                                                        client_id)
    if not token_response.get('accessToken', None):
        return None

    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update({'Authorization': f'Bearer {token_response["accessToken"]}',
                            'SdkVersion': 'sample-python-adal',
                            'x-client-SKU': 'sample-python-adal'})
    return session
```

Comment: If you want to call the access token without signing in with user, you could try to use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). This is the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/data-lake-analytics-python-auth-options/tree/master/#authenticate-non-interactively-with-a-secret-key) with Python.

Comment: Starting June 30th, 2020, we will no longer add new features to ADAL. We'll continue adding critical security fixes to ADAL until June 30th, 2022. After this date, your apps using ADAL will continue to work, but we recommend upgrading to MSAL to take advantage of the latest features. Using Daemon app you can acquire a token to call a Graph API on behalf of itself (not on behalf of a user). It uses the standard OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow. Python with MSAL using [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-python-daemon).

Comment: Thanks @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity - I essentially scrapped the code above and switched to MSAL, and was able to accomplish what I need using SerializableTokenCache, as seen here: https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#msal.SerializableTokenCache

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Can i move this to answer so that it would help others.

Answer (score -1):

(Moving from comments to answer)

Starting June 30th, 2020, we will no longer add new features to ADAL. We'll continue adding critical security fixes to ADAL until June 30th, 2022. After this date, your apps using ADAL will continue to work, but we recommend upgrading to MSAL to take advantage of the latest features. Using Daemon app you can acquire a token to call a Graph API on behalf of itself (not on behalf of a user). It uses the standard OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow. Python with MSAL using client [credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-python-daemon).

User was able to to resolve the issue by migrating to Msal and  was able to accomplish this requirement using SerializableTokenCache by following the [document](https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#msal.SerializableTokenCache).